# How to Use VBA To Look for Match with 2 Columns With ANOTHER 2 Columns?

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am trying to compare the rows in Columns A and B against Columns D and E. To be more specific, the rows in Columns A and B will be copied and pasted into another sheet if it matches any of the rows in Columns D and E.

I have tried combining MATCH, INDEX, VLOOKUP formulas but I have so far only been able to detect duplicates and not match the rows exactly.

Here is an example of my data:

[image]

The rows in Column A and B will be copied and pasted into another sheet if it matches any of the rows in Column D and E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pieced this together with some comments to help you understand the approach.

This uses [an array](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm) that isn't seen on the sheet. This is similar to a "helper column" if you were to put on in `Column F` to concatenate your values. You can see how to modify what/where the macro makes updates in the first couple rows (right now it's based on your screen shot).

You can [download the workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gfxiEz8awqBpIwuHlg) that I used as an example and has the working option.

```
Sub TryingToclear2500Points()

Const theFirstColoumns As String = "A:B"
Const theSecondColumns As String = "D:E"
Const theDestinantionComun As String = "A:B"
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1 'Worksheet you want to analyse the columns
Dim psheet As Worksheet: Set psheet = Sheet2 'worksheet to paste data to
Dim checkRNG As Range, i As Long


'establishes destination column
     Dim dCOlumn As Long
     dCOlumn = Range(theDestinantionComun).Cells(1, 1).Column


'this is similiar to a helper column in that it makes an 1 dimensional array 
'of the columns concatenated together
    Set checkRNG = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range(theSecondColumns))
    With checkRNG
    
    'builds an array to hold the data
    ReDim Makealist(1 To checkRNG.Rows.Count) As String
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
    
        'if using excel 2016 or higher TextJoin might be good for more dynamic
        'Makealist(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("", False, Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count)))
        
        'this will always work if just two columns
        Makealist(i) = .Cells(i, 1).Value2 & .Cells(i, 2).Value2
    
    Next i
    
    End With
    
'now loop through columns A and b and check for a match in the array MakeAList)
                
    Set checkRNG = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range(theFirstColoumns))
    
        With checkRNG
        
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        
        
            'check if match
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & .Cells(i, 2).Value2, Makealist, 0)) Then
                'found a match
                
                'using copy paste
                'Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Copy _
                    psheet.Cells(Rows.Count, dCOlumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
                'If you just want values, below is a better method that just sends values
                psheet.Cells(Rows.Count, dCOlumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
                    Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Value2
                
            End If
        Next i

     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply was just home. Anyways tried running the code and I get an error which say Type mismatch on this particular line of the code: Makealist(i) = .Cells(i, 1).Value2 & .Cells(i, 2).Value2
Is there anyway to solve this? Sorry as I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: Assuming you're working directly with that screenshot, it's probably because you have errors in column B. Figure out a way to get rid of those and you should be good. Also figure out what row it is by identifying the value of `i` when the error hits. Probably confrim that it's related to the `N/A`

Comment: Okay got it! Seems like I have to remove all the #N/A's from the data before I was able to run the Macro. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, I am now trying this on the main file which I am working on and have an error on this line of code: If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & .Cells(i, 2).Value2, Makealist, 0)) Then
I am also getting the Type mismatch error once again and am not very sure what this line of code does, would appreciate if you could explain and help out. Thank you!

Comment: Also on the main file I am working on, the data in Columns A and B and Columns D and E are not the same can that be the cause? If so, is there anyway to fix that. Thank you!

Comment: Update, it works when the number of rows are the same. However I need it to work even when the number of rows are different. Anyway to edit to code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't clear to me if you want to do this using code (in which PGCodeRider's answer is excellent) or on a manual basis.

If it is manual you can just put this statement in Column C and copy it down:

```
=IF(A2&B2=D2&E2,"MATCH","")
```

This will add the word "MATCH" if Column A and B combined are the same as Column D and E combined (and leave the cell empty if they don't match). You can then filter or sort on Column C for "MATCH" and copy the rows.

If you wanted it so that if Column A OR Column B matched D and E respectively then change the formula to

=IF(OR(A2=D2, B2=E2),"MATCH","")

This assumes that you won't have blank entries in the columns though (if so you need to extend the formula to ignore empty cells using the AND function).

Answer (score -1):

Try using "IF" condition on column A and B